# how to fetch and display selected items from DropDownList to Text box using javascrtipt/HTML/AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Could anyone tell me, how to fetch and selected items from DropDownList to Text box using javascrtipt/HTML/AngularJs.

In detail:

- I've a dropdownlist which has lot of items with its.
- If I click one from that list means it should displayed in new textbox after clicking add button,
- If I click one more, then click add button means it should show the text box followed by previous   box.. like one by one whenever I want add new items to show from dropdown..

Hope you understand. Please help me to solve this

Comment: Some genuine efforts with code is much appreciated rather than asking for solutions.

Comment: here is an example in the doc.https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Answer (score 0):

Simple example extracted from the doc:

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/MzVTi2dtbq2Sv2jgwLYs?p=preview)

JS:

```
(function(angular) {

angular.module('nonStringSelect', [])
  .run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.model = { id: 2 };
  })

})(window.angular);
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="nonStringSelect">
  <select ng-model="model.id">
  <option value="0">Zero</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
{{ model }}
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Huan Feng...!!!! but i already saw it. it is okay but i need it with slight change, nothing but, selected values should be shown in TextBox and should be added if want more. For Example: there is 25 items in list if select 1st it should shown in text box, if i ciick another means it shown as similar as previous one after clicking add button and so on..

Comment: maybe you can write your code first, and let me know where is the problem

Comment: the above code is okay.. am going to use that, there's no problem with that..   this is my code  
<select ng-model="model.id" >
    




  <option value=""></option>
  

  <option value="Material 1">hi</option>
  <option value="Material 2>hello</option>
  <option value="Material 3">Good2SeeYou</option>
  
  
 <input type="text" id="{{ model.id}}" ><br>
</select>   if user pick on from drpDwn it shoud be shown in text box and could add as per his/her reqirement

Comment: am confused with using ID to fetch data from drpDwn and display it on text box..!!!

Comment: Exactly..!!! but i want to add more items and display those in more textboxes whenever user select multiple values

Comment: I think you can try to figure it out yourself, you already know the basic stuff like how to set the value from the dropdown selection. It's not difficult:)

Comment: yeah, you're right..truly am trying  to get the solution.. :)